# Google Sheets How to secure formula

Tags: google-sheets

I have a problem. Here is my formula. She tells how many days are gone today.

=IF(ISBLANK(F8);"-";IF(TODAY()>=F8;CONCATENATE(TODAY()-F8;" dni temu");"Podano złą datę")).

Can u tell me how I can protect it before other editors? I tried to move it to a hidden sheet, but I'm using filters in the main sheet, and it's not working well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned that you do not want your users to see the exact formula you are using and protecting the cells still allows the users to copy and paste the values on them, you can use a workaround by creating a custom function for Google Sheets using Google Apps Script.

In this case I created the function called `secretFunction`, so whenever you want to use it you can just call the function in any cell for example: `=secretFunction(F8)` and that will show the exact same thing as the given formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(F8);"-";IF(TODAY()>=F8;CONCATENATE(TODAY()-F8;" days ago");"Error"))
```

Here is the code you need to use:

```
function secretFunction(date){
  if(date != "")
  {
    let today = new Date();
    today.setHours(00, 00, 00, 00);
    let dateValue = new Date(date);
    let total = Math.trunc(((today - dateValue) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)));
    let message = `${total} days ago.`;
    if(today >= dateValue)
    {
      return message;
    }
    else
    {
      return "Error";
    }
  }
  else return "-";
}
```

You can update the name of the function to anything you prefer, and the function will just need to read the date value you want to use. This way the users will just be able to see the function but they will not be able to use it in any other file since it will be linked only to this file with the script you create.

Here is an example of the results I get depending on the value that is used with the function. The left side is the input value and the result is on the right side:

[image]

References:

- [Protect cells in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308980?hl=en#:%7E:text=Note%3A%20Even%20if%20you%20protect%20content%2C%20people%20can%20still%20print%2C%20copy%2C%20paste%2C%20import%2C%20and%20export%20copies%20of%20it.)
- [Custom functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Comment: I know, but they can still copy it and paste in other cells. I don't want it ;( And if I hide formula bar it's hidden just on my account.

Comment: @AlYanko That would be expected according to the [official documentation](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308980?hl=en#:~:text=Note%3A%20Even%20if%20you%20protect%20content%2C%20people%20can%20still%20print%2C%20copy%2C%20paste%2C%20import%2C%20and%20export%20copies%20of%20it.). I can think of a couple workarounds but some of them are related to Google Apps Script. Are you willing to use it or would you prefer avoiding it and just use the regular UI from Google Sheets?

Comment: I'll add some scripts anyway, so if that going to help me, why not? What are u thinking about?

Comment: @AlYanko In that case you can just create the same formula as a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) and then just call the function in the cell. That way the users will see you are calling a function but no one will know what the function does in the background.

Comment: @AlYanko if they try to copy it they will just copy something like =nameOfFunction() but they will not know what it does and can not be used out of that sheet file.

Comment: OOo, that's what I need. I'll try it. Thanks you

Comment: But i dont have any skills in Java? Can u help me? How i can change it into my custom function?
=IF(ISBLANK(F8);"-";IF(TODAY()>=F8;CONCATENATE(TODAY()-F8;" days ago");"Error")).

Comment: @AlYanko what type of value do you have in cell F8? Is it a date? Are you pulling that value from that specific cell all the time?

Comment: F8 is a DD-MM-YYYY format. I have this formula for ca. 40 cells. From F8-F48.

Comment: @AlYanko I have updated the answer with the code you need to use. Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Works :) But if I put 09.05.2022 function show 2.25 days ago. 
One ask more. Can I "limit" this function? Because I want to show this function from A4:A44, but if "Editor" add a new line, this function will work for this new line too. "=secretFunction(A45).

Comment: @AlYanko I edited the script once again. Let me know if that works. I was not able to get the same result with the same input you mentioned but this change should fix the problem. Now, about the other question, if I am not mistaken it is possible by using an onEdit trigger to detect if an edit on the sheet was made out of that range and if the edit contains the name of the custom function. It would be similar to [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/90929/how-to-restrict-a-google-script-to-a-certain-cell-range).